# MYSQL name field not taking name in other languages

Tags: mysql

I have this field

```
display_name    varchar(30) latin1_swedish_ci
```

it takes English names as usual, but this database deals in different languages, and also users from all around enter there names, some of which are in different languages. french lets say, and a name stored in french is displayed like this `???????`
what could be the reason? i believe it has something to do with this `latin1_swedish_ci` how can i make this field generic to take and display any name in any language correctly?

Comment: Set the Character set to "utf8" and Collation to "utf8_unicode_ci" that can be set in the MySQL Config file (my.cnf/my.ini) as mentioned here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html. You can set the character set and collation while creating a database as `CREATE DATABASE database_name           DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`                                                  https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog also serves the purpose if you are looking for a GUI solution in setting the character set and collation to individual databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Also refer: [10.1.10 Unicode Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html)

Or the other way is to use utf-8 in MYSQL by adding this to your my.cnf:

> ```
> collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
> character_set_server = utf8
> ```

and when you are executing your query the first use these two queries:

> ```
> SET NAMES 'utf8';
> CHARSET 'utf8';
> ```

Comment: or, i just changed my field type to utf8_general_ci, that seems to be working too

Answer (score 0):

if php code for connect to mysql,add code to (class mysql or code):

```
$dbLink = mysql_connect($argHost, $argUsername, $argPassword);
 mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $dbLink);
```

and add code in meta tag to html code in head :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

======================================================================

or

To set the default to UTF-8, you want to add the following to my.cnf

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```